# How to train a model on a data where there are multiple data inside a data point?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I'm trying to do prediction on capacity column, however each data point consist of more data.

I tried exploding the dataset and copying the capacity values to each row, but that shouldn't be the case because each row will get different capacity predicted. Is there a way to train such kind of dataset?

[image]

Comment: A very relevant question is: _why_ does each data point have multiple data points? Are these values grouped by the capacity? How does each nested data element relate to the prediction target?

Comment: Actually each data point represent a **cycle** data. Each cycle has **a** capacity. Each cycle runs for some time duration, and in that duration some data is collected over which capacity is dependant

Comment: You might try asking this on the [datascience.se] stack site, as they can have more insight into theory and technique, while stackoverflow is more about specific coding issues, and there you might find someone with more domain-specific experience or knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Are the sizes of each entry consistent? If so you can explode your data set into different columns (current_battery0, current_battery1, ...) each being a different predictor. You are losing some information that way perhaps but this might work well for you.

Comment: No, size is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

the image doesn't shown . however, if each data point A consist of more data points A={a1,a2,a3,..an} try to take the mean or median of these points {a1,a2,a3,..an} and assign the resulting value to A :
A=mean or median {an}

Comment: I don't think its a good idea. In that I loose lot of information